# Why R resets dataframe column after function call?

Tags: r, dataframe

I made simple R script and run:

```
f <- data.frame(x = c(1,1))
f$y <- NA

test <- function(n) {
  f$y[1] <- 1
  print(f)
}

test(0)
print(f)
```

the result is

```
> test(0)
  x  y
1 1  1
2 1 NA
> print(f)
  x  y
1 1 NA
2 1 NA
>
```

I would expect in the final output (1, 1) (1, NA) but for some reason f$y[1] had been reset to NA.

When I inline the function, the result are ok.

Why function call has this side effect on dataframe column? 
Is it avoidable?

Comment: In functional programming, functions shouldn't have *side effects*. This means that if a function changes a data frame, the change is only local to the function. If you want the change to be available outside the function, the function should `return()` the data frame and you should assign the result.

Comment: Your problem seems to be not that the *"function call has this side effect of data frame column"*, but rather than your data frame is unchanged after running the function - it has no effect whatsoever on your data frame (outside of it's internal copy).

Comment: So I need to write f <- test(f) in my code to keep the changes. Or better rewrite it and return another, 'result' data frame with only y column. Right?

Comment: Change the last line of the function to just `f` or `return(f)` (R is flexible) and then run `f <- test(f)`.

Comment: You shouldn't `print()` in a function - you should just `return(f)`. To return the whole `f` data frame, or just return a vector (the `y` column) or return a new data frame with just the `y` column is up to you - depends how you want your function to work and how you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
f <- data.frame(x = c(1,1))

f$y <- NA

test <- function(f) {
  f$y[1] <- 1
  return(f)
}

f <- test(f)
print(f)
x  y
1 1  1
2 1 NA
```